# Why do I need cleanup in useEffect in react

Tags: reactjs

Im new to react and Im not sure why do we need a cleanup function when dealing with EventListeners, Iam trying to set an event when resizing my window but i only have 1 event in (Elements -> Event Listeners) tab in chrome dev tools, even if I don't return a cleanup function in my hook

Heres my code:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", function checksize() {
      console.log("1");
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should absolutely avoid using that in your code, because on each rerender, it is going to add a new event listener to the window.

Secondly, to answer your question, you should have a cleanup effect to remove event listeners and other similar mechanisms to avoid **memory leaks**. If you don't clean them up, then you leave dangling eventlisteners taking up memory which is not a good idea, and may be picked up on within your other components as well. So the ideal way to handle this kind of code is

```
 const logOne = () => console.log("1"); //put the function reference in a variable so that you can remove the event afterwards

 useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", logOne);

   return () => {
     window.removeEventListener("resize", logOne); //remove event listener on unmount
   }
  }, []); //empty dependency array so that function only runs on first render, so that consequent rerenders don't cause you to add more of these event listeners
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured if I have a useState it would add more listeners because of re-renders.

Answer (score 1):

Because you will keep adding listeners every render. Instead of printing "1" once, it will print it twice next time. Then 3 times on the next re-render and so on.

Comment: I have tested it and it still add 1 on every 1 px resize.

Comment: that is probably because your component has not gone through a single rerender yet. and that is ofcourse possible on very simple components, but real world will never be that simple

Comment: You are probably correct, I was missing a useState